# Any way to pass HTML through a RESTful URL?

Tags: html, rest, email

So I have a basic emailer setup in my company. It is a REST API GET call that has a URL like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/emailer?email=to@person.here&subject=test&body=test
```

For the body= I want to pass HTML for an HTML email.

e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/emailer?email=to@person.here&subject=test&body=<html><head></head><body>test</body></html>
```

I have tried simply passing HTML in there and the site threw an error.

From what I have read it might not be possible. I might need to take in a file and convert it within the code for HTML. The code in the API takes a string and it doesn't care about the html so there is something here about passing certain character in a URL or in a RESTful URL. I am new to RESTful so I have been reading a lot but this area seems to be missing details.

Comment: Are you URL/Percent Encoding (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) your HTML before adding it to the URL?

Comment: This isn't that great of a question. Please see [ask].

Comment: Ito, I am mixing your link with Zeb's below. Still having issues so I may try to pass a file next but that is an entirely different story.

Answer (score 1):

GET parameters must be encoded, replacing any characters which aren't allowed in the body of a parameter (`?`, `&`, `=`, and spaces for instance) as a percent sign followed by two numbers (`%3F`, `%26`, `%3D`, and `%20` for instance). Luckily, in most languages you don't have to worry about doing this manually.

JavaScript has a function called `encodeURIComponent` which you can use as such: `encodeURIComponent(html)`.

Python has a package called `urllib.parse` which contains a function called `quote` which you can use as such:

```
from urllib.parse import quote

# ...

encoded = quote(html)
```

Other languages have similar methods, just search "<language name> encode URI" on Google.

Comment: At the moment we will not be using an app to send the data over we will be dropping the above URL into a browser. So any coding would have to be done manually. With that said I can get something brewed up in powershell to do the conversion for folks until the front end is done. I am testing this now.